# react-select force force option

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a select defined:

```
<Select value={brand} menuPortalTarget={document.body} isSearchable={ true } fullWidth placeholder="Search Brand" options={getBrand} className="select indent" onChange={handleBrandChange}
```

getBrand is the options. What I want to do is prepend onto this list of options "No Brand" without editing array that getBrand comes from to populate the options.